# exponential kernel

Tags: analysis

If $f(x)\in L^2(0,1)$, we consider the operator "exponential kernel" the aplication:

$$W(f(x))=f(x) + 2 \int_0^x e^{x-t}f(t)dt.  \quad x\in (0,1).$$

Then, my teacher ask me 3 questions. I have done one of that questions. But i don´t find any information. Someone could help me? someone could say me some book? i need read or find any information about "exponential kernel".

Maybe my teacher call "exponential kernel", but in the reality, this exercise has another name.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Initial remark: I don't know if you will find something with keyword "exponential kernel" (usually reserved do exponentials of the form $e^{-|x|}$.)

Nevertheless, I think it is good to know that this kind of issue is equivalent to solve a differential equation. Here is why:

Setting $g(x):=W(f(x))$, write your operator as:

$$\tag{1}g(x)=f(x) + 2 e^x\int_0^x e^{-t}f(t)dt$$

When you differentiate it (the second expression is differentiated as a product (and by application of $\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x\varphi(t)dt=\varphi(x)$):

$$g'(x)=f'(x)+2e^x\int_0^x e^{-t}f(t)dt+2e^xe^{-x}f(x)$$

$$\tag{2}g'(x)=f'(x)+2e^x\int_0^x e^{-t}f(t)dt+2f(x)$$

But $(1)$ can be written under the form:$$\tag{3}\int_0^x e^{-t}f(t)dt=\frac12e^{-x}(g(x)-f(x))$$

Plugging $(3)$ into $(2)$ gives the differential equation

$$\tag{4}g'(x)=f'(x)+2e^x\frac12e^{-x}(g(x)-f(x))+f(x)$$

which can be simplified into:

$$\tag{5}g'(x)-g(x)=f'(x)$$

which is a differential equation with unknown function $g$ (the RHS being known).